# How do I dig into the rendering performance in the chrome console?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

One of my web components is taking a long time to render in chrome (multiple seconds of screen freeze when it loads the data).

The same component renders almost instantly in Firefox.

When debugging performance, I can see that a lot of time is spent rendering in chrome, but I can't see a way to dig into it to see if perhaps there's certain style rules that are taking a long time. The other tabs seem to only indicate which events *caused* a re-render, rather than breaking down the rendering time itself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to minify your rendering time:

- Minify Unnecessary Codes.
- Limit The Number of External Resources in the HEAD.
- Defer Loading Javascript. ...
- Make Use of HTTP/2 Protocol.
- Cache on the Client-side.

---

Articles:

- https://web.dev/critical-rendering-path-render-tree-construction/
- https://edgemesh.com/blog/how-to-improve-your-website-start-render-time

Comment: Good advice and something I'm going to be looking at, however the current rendering time in Firefox is good, whereas chrome is terrible. Whilst general good practice will help it seems that there is something specific that chrome does differently which results in wildly different rendering times. I'd like to be able to pinpoint that difference so I can target the improvements rather than taking shots in the dark.